# Segmentation fault error on 10.7.5

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am executing a program through command prompt inside my application. This is working fine on OSX 10.8.5, 10.9.x versions without any issue. But my application also need to run on 10.7.5. Same code fails on 10.7.5 when command gets executed. I looked at the command string which gets executed, This is correct. Any idea of this issue?

I am getting below error:

```
/bin/sh: line 1:  1028 Segmentation fault: 11
```

Below is the code I use to execute command.

```
NSTask *task;
    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/sh"];

    NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          @"-c" ,
                          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", commandToRun],
                          nil];
    //NSLog(@"run command: %@",commandToRun);
    [task setArguments: arguments];

    NSPipe *pipe;
    pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe];

    NSFileHandle *file;
    file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

    [task launch];

    NSData *data;
    data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

    NSString *output;
    output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return output;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the issue. Executable which ran through the command was not compiled for lower OSX versions.

Adding the flag –mmacosx-version-min=10.7 and recompiling executable solved the problem.

If you are getting Segmentation fault: 11 or "Illegal instruction: 4" error message when you execute the exe command, you may want to check at the –mmacosx-version-min first before getting into further memory related debugging.